# Azure Files are Very Slow

Tags: azure-storage-account, azure-files

I'm mounting an Azure Files SMB share to a Windows 10 computer via the script generated by Portal:

```
$connectTestResult = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net -Port 445
if ($connectTestResult.TcpTestSucceeded) {
    # Save the password so the drive will persist on reboot
    cmd.exe /C "cmdkey /add:`"storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net`" /user:`"localhost\storageaccountname`" /pass:`"q/Password==`""
    # Mount the drive
    New-PSDrive -Name R -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net\database" -Persist
} else {
    Write-Error -Message "Unable to reach the Azure storage account via port 445. Check to make sure your organization or ISP is not blocking port 445, or use Azure P2S VPN, Azure S2S VPN, or Express Route to tunnel SMB traffic over a different port."
}
```

And when I copy the files from that file share to local computer, I'm getting a very low copy speed of
1-3 MB/s.

Why is it is so slow and how can I increase it?

Answer (score 1):

Performance depends on multiple factors such as network throughput, latency and many more,  Please use this URL to determine the latency: https://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/Latency .

Something similar discussed here with good artefacts: Please have look.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/621022/slow-upload-speed-azure-file-share-network-drive.html which gives more idea on your scenario.

This [article lists some common problems related to Azure file shares.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshooting-files-performance) It provides potential causes and workarounds for when you encounter these problems.

Additional information:

- If you don't have a specific minimum I/O size requirement, we recommend that you use 1 MiB as the I/O size for optimal performance.

For testing purpose can you use **[Azcopy tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10)** and check the speed and let me know the status. For transferring Files I would recommend to use AzCopy and File Storage for any transfer files(upload and download). In Azcopy throughput from a single instance will scale at least 20Gbps

Sometimes your proxies/VMs or whatever runs in the same datacenter, network requests does not leave the local network and the speed then depends on the infrastructure. (routers, firewalls, cables, etc). I'm sure they won't limit speed between their own infrastructure so services hosted on the same network works at full speed.

[Scalability and performance targets for standard storage accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account#azure-files-scale-targets)